# Querying remote system via WMI returns access denied for non-administrator

Tags: security, wmi, remote-access, dcom

I have a simple WMI query that runs fine locally, but querying a remote system gives an access denied error. When I add the local user to the remote system as member of the administrator group, the query works as expected, but I don't want to have that user as a member of that group.

I already tried the following things, unfortunately not successful so far:

- I enabled RemoteAdmin for the firewall (netsh firewall set service RemoteAdmin enable)
- I added the user with all possible access rights to the WMI Security settings (for the root name space, and I also checked that the settings are correctly propagated to the namespace I'm querying, root/cimv2) via wmimgmt.msc
- I enabled remote access for the user in DCOM COM security

I still get the same error every time I run my query, is there anything else that I may have missed?

Comment: What Windows versions are on the local and remote systems?

Comment: There is a MSDN section dedicated to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Both systems use Windows 2008 Server (64 bit). I've read through the linked article, but it looks like I tried everything that's in there. Do I have to reboot the system for the changed DCOM settings to have an effect?

Comment: The failure is dependent on what your simple WMI script is trying to do. Please post it.

Answer (score 1):

WMI rights are much tighter than typical, as the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290%28VS.85%29.aspx) provided by Uros describes in detail. In short, you will either need to enable the Active Directory right called "Trusted for Delegation", which is *extremely* powerful and not recommended, or add explicit credentials, as described in the MS link referenced by Uros.